In Resque with Redis, how to get worker-id from job-id
We miss that info. We have 2 production machines, and we would like to know in which machine has been executed.
We have the job-id, like 9e806647228a11654d46fb0705c2d209, but... how do we know the worker-pid, so we could find where that worker was running?
Our resque release is v2.6.0, connected to Redis v1.8.2 with client v3.3.5.
Rails 3.8
We have search in all the places in the front, but we can not find that information.
